# Type Hint that this is a Subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

How does one indicate via type hints that one class is a subclass of another?  Eg.

```
class Foo:
  def foo(self, x):
    pass

def dynamic() -> Type[Foo]:
  class SubFoo(Foo):
    pass

  return SubFoo

class SubSubFoo(dynamic()):
  def f|  # no suggestions from my editor
```

My editor (PyCharm) does not provide suggestions in the above case, indicating that static analysis does not recognize that `SubSubFoo` is a subtype of `Foo`.  How can I use type hints to indicate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer from JetBrains indicating that this is a limitation of PyCharm rather than a limitation or misuse of type hints:

> In this particular case it's IDE limitation, we don't look inside dynamic() function as it may be a lot more complex.
>
> -[Andrey Resler](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007660479-Autosuggest-Missing-when-Subclassing-Non-Constant)

As a fix, I am using an idiom where whenever I subclass `dynamic()` I will also subclass `Foo` after that, which leads to the desired suggestions appearing without altering the logic of the program (even if it does look a bit weird).